# How do I view active Google maps events using dev tools?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

Google Maps seems to have its own [event listener system](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event). How do I view these listeners in dev tools? For the life of me I cannot find it the normal way under elements>Event Listeners.

I use React and in the useEffect() cleanup it makes sense to me to remove listeners. So I am looking to make sure setup and teardown works correctly. I have had memory leaks with other listeners in the past when I fail to do this. So that is the context.

Answer (score 0):

## You can check the object where you added the listener

For example, you can log in the console the marker that you have created and go deeper into its event listener object through `marker.__e3_.click`.

Here's a sample code that shows an object of a marker if it is has an event Listener or not:

```
    // instantiate the marker
    marker = new Marker({
        map,
        draggable: true,
        position: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    })
    
    // This adds a click event listener to your marker 
    let markerListenerEvent = event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        alert("you have clicked the marker!")
    });
    
    // this will show in the console that 
    // the marker now have a click event listener.
    console.log("clickable marker: ");
    console.log(marker.__e3_.click[64].So);
    // this will return "true"
    
    
  // clicking on the map will then remove the listener you put
    // on the marker
    let mapListenerEvent = event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
        alert("You have now removed the marker event listener!")
        // This is the the method that removes the listener for marker above
        event.removeListener(markerListenerEvent);
        
        // this will show in the console that 
        // the marker now don't have a click event listener
        // since the "click" object will now be empty.
        console.log("not clickable marker: ");
        console.log(marker.__e3_.click);
        // this will return an empty object because the listener has been removed
    })
```

If you are not using a Google Maps React Library but just plain ReactJS, this should work just fine.

Here's a proof of concept snippet that you can play around with (Please use your own API KEY): https://jsbin.com/jovajor/1/edit?html,js,output

> *NOTE: I used an external playground so that you can check the console.*

Hope this helps!